# How to call from C# to CEFSharp that run a web page using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cefsharp

I have created a c# app that embed CEFSharp. From C#, I can call a javascript function using cefsharp.ExecuteScriptAsync.
e.g. in javsscript, I have a function `showAlertFromClient(msg)`
from c#, I can call this Javascript function using

`cefsharp.ExecuteScriptAsync("showAlertFromClient('Hi from C#');");`

However, the web page is done using React and I have no idea on how to expose a function in react where I can call it from c#.

e.g. of react, index.js
`import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './App';
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>, document.getElementById('root'));`

So do I expose a JS function e.g. `showAlertFromClient()` in React where I can call if from c#?
Anyone have any idea how to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a new.js file and add your method(showAlertFromClient) in this file. Call this function like

```
cefsharp.ExecuteScriptAsync("showAlertFromClient('Hi from C#');");
```

Include this file in head of index.html.

inside your method use window.anyname('anything'.):

```
showAlertFromClient('Hi from C#'){
   window.updateUi('Hi from C#');
```

}

In component of react.js

```
componentWillMount() {
window.updateUi= (data) => {
  this.setState({
    newData: data
  });
}
```